# How to insert or include package using pyinstaller in python?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I use library pptx, Pyinstaller.

I'm trying to include pptx library in an .EXE file using Pyinstaller.

But the EXE file log output is:

```
pptx.packagenotfounderror.
```

How can i include pptx library in EXE file?

Please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bundling data files with PyInstaller (--onefile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile)

Answer (score 0):

Well when working with PyInstaller, it's always useful to know

- What flags you used
- The content of your .spec file

It would be useful to see the two above.

You don't need to explicitly add a library. If you imported it somewhere in your code, PyInstaller will notice and add it accordingly.